# Products appearing in Weierstrass factorization

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

I am playing a bit with the Weierstrass factorization of entire functions and I have a question on bounds.

Let $a_k$'s be such that $\sum_{k\ge0}a_k^{-1}$ converges and let
$$ f(z) = \prod_{k\ge0}\left(1 - \frac{z}{a_k} \right) .$$

What is the order of $f$? Is it majorated?

Similarly if $\sum_{k\ge0}b_k^{-2}$ and
$$ g(z) = \prod_{k\ge0}\left(1 - \frac{z^2}{b_k^2} \right) ,$$
what is the order of $g$? Is it majorated?

Is there a standard way to deal with this kind of questions?